# Is it possible to run a code from Azure repo, as a function app with scheduler?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

So I've finished my backend and frontend part of the project.

Now big aspect of my project is scraper function, which is implemented in the backend side of the code. Right now, I need to open VS code every day, and run a function which will trigger the scrapers. Now I've researched about, and Azure has a function apps which has a scheduled function.

Now what I want is: I want just to call a file inside my Azure repo. My backend and frontend are in the different repos, and I want to run file `scraping-service.js` inside `scraping` folder in order to scrape data and insert the data into the db.

Now normally I run pipeline with `azure-service.yml` which has its own configuration for running my project. Is any way to implement this function to run just `scraping-service.js` at certain time of the day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any way to implement this function to run just scraping-service.js at certain time of the day?

In Azure Pipeline, you could set schedules for pipelines.

Here is a doc about the detailed info: [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

For example: In yaml pipeline , you could set `cron` .

```
trigger:
  - main

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'xxx'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'stanbackapp'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'stanbackapp'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main   

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '10.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'

          - script: |
              npm install
              npm run build --if-present
              npm run test --if-present
            displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: 'Archive files'
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: zip
              archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              replaceExistingArchive: true

          - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            artifact: drop

  - stage: Build1
    displayName: Build1 stage
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
    jobs:
      - job: Build1
        displayName: Build1
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '10.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'
          
          - task: CmdLine@2
            inputs:
              script: ' node $(build.sourcesdirectory)/scraping/scraping-service.js'



  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: $(environmentName)
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureWebApp@1
                  displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: stanbackapp'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                    appType: webAppLinux
                    appName: $(webAppName)
                    runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
                    package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
                    startUpCommand: 'npm run dev'
```

In this case, when the pipeline is triggered by schedules, it will run Single file, or it will run the whole pipeline.

You can also add condition to task level.

Comment: Interesting, would you say it is a valid way to run some application code (not related to the build process at all) as the OP wants to do?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyj3nz1d/ Is it possible to implement that into this .yaml?

Comment: NOTE: I just want to run my file, not to run whole pipeline every eg. 12 hours

Comment: @Aldinho. You may consider using the condition in your yaml pipeline. It can decide what to run based on the trigger method. Please refer to my update

Comment: so with this I just implement under the `steps` eg. `stage B` that code previously with `cron`?

Comment: Yes.  you are right .  Add the cron before the stages.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jnaqv91k/ Will something like this work?

Comment: @Aldinho it may not work .  You need to add the schedules before stages. Please refer to my sample in answer. You need to make some small changes. And you need to add condition for each stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229032/discussion-between-aldinho-and-kevin-lu-msft).

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to create an azure devops pipeline that deploys the code you want to run to an azure function when the code changes. So put the code of `scraping-service.js` in the function or have the function call the method in `scraping-service.js`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-functions?view=azure-devops&tabs=nodejs%2Cyaml#deploy-with-azure-function-app)

Although there might be ways to run the code in an Azure Devops pipeline I don't think it is meant to run application code. You won't have the monitoring capabilities an azure function gives you, nor the availability of scaling, configuration and all the thing Azure Functions provides.